# Black screen on second monitor

Tags: 16.04

Just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.x to 16.04. I have a dual monitor setup. However I get nothing but a black screen on the second monitor, which is detected by Ubuntu. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried configuring dual monitor again after the upgrade

Answer (score 0):

The drivers likely dont support it. I had the same trouble with a macbook on ubuntu
, so i installed the nvidia drivers. Which worked until a system upgrade completely wrecjed everything and was firced to boot into grub to uninstall them